# Adding port number to Elastic IP in domain name integration using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, port, amazon-route53

I want to add my port number to my Elastic IP to integrating into my domain.But it won't allow adding a port.  It only allows me to add my Elastic IP.How can I add my port to my elastic IP? Like, my domain is `www.xxyyzz.com` and I want to add my Elastic IP `xx.xx.xx.xx` and my port:8888 to that domain name. If i run www.xxyyzz.com it will point `xx.xx.xx.xx:8888`. How can I achieve this? Or is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally ,I solved the problem using iptables to redirect any request to my own port 8888. I used below command to redirect all the request fro 80 to 8888. Now it works fine.

> sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888

Answer (score 2):

You should use a reverse proxy as nginx to do it. It's no a DNS rule.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-domain-name.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://X.X.X.X:8888;
    }
}
```